# How to handle nested RecyclerView updates

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-jetpack, nestedrecyclerview

I have implemented a view with a parent `RecyclerView` and a nested one. The nested `RecyclerView` contains Cards with items of a shopping card, that need to be updated when the user clicks on them (by showing a badge with the purchased quantity).

Both recyclers work with their `ListAdapter` with the `DiffUtil.ItemCallback`.

The point is the implementation of the outer ListAdapter `areContentsTheSame` of the `DiffUtil.ItemCallback` object: if it return `false` when the quantity changes, the quantity badge of the inner recycler is never updated. If it returns `true`, the entire inner `RecyclerView` is redrawn.

```
object ListDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<CategoryWithItems>() {
    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: CategoryWithItems, newItem: CategoryWithItems): Boolean {
        var result oldItem.category.name == newItem.category.name
        oldItem.itemQuantityList?.forEachIndexed { index, value ->
            result = result && value.item.quantity == newItem.itemQuantityList?.get(index)?.item?.quantity
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

So my question is: how can I redraw only the clicked card of the inner `RecyclerView`?

Comment: Check this out if it helps https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/notifying-recyclerview-on-a-specific-change-b36e6dc59e0f